# How do I prevent my bread crust from drying out?

Tags: baking, bread

When I make bread pizza or toasted sandwiches in my oven, the outer crust dries out. Which elements should I use for baking to prevent it from drying out?
My oven is 35 liters with convection.

Comment: Are you cooking on top of a pizza/baking stone, a metal sheet pan, a screen or perforated metal pan, or something else?

Answer (score 2):

Personally I've always found the best way to ensure a soft crust after baking is, while they are cooling on the side, to throw a clean damp cloth over the top. Only for a little while say 5-10mins and ensure the cloth is only damp, not soaking.

Comment: Along the same lines, I often brush or drip water on the edges of the crust if they dry out to soften and re-hydrate them - either during cooking or after the food's out.  It gives me more control over where and how much it softens, which I like - though the damp cloth has the benefit of being easy, so I may well steal the technique :)

Comment: Easy and there's just something I Love about the steaming cloth/bread batch in the corner of my workbench.

Answer (score 0):

For making pizza at home, the best method is to use well-rested dough on a pizza stone at max temperature (probably ~290 C).

Here are the basic steps:

---

1. Allow dough to rest for several hours
2. Preheat pizza stone in oven at max temperature for about 1 hour
3. Shape dough and cook by itself for about 4 minutes (crust should be somewhat firm on outside, but airy on inside)
4. Take out crust and add toppings
5. Put back in oven for about 7 minutes more (until cheese starts bubbling)

---

This is what I do every time I make pizza at home, and the result is very consistent. Just watch the crust the first couple times to get the timing down. You also should be sure that the dough isn't too dry when mixing it.

---

For sandwiches, just brush some water periodically on the top, this will keep it from browning too quickly.